# how to open a picker using c# backend code .Net Maui

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, maui

hey i am hiding a picker behind an entry. how can i trigger the picker to open the list item from backend code.

```
picker.focus()
```

I tried the above code but it is not working. any other way?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Because the command is right, but if you are hiding it maybe you will need to unhide first or hide the entry to picker appear.

Comment: no the picker works fine if i click outside of the entry that is above it. i have an entry focused event and i want the picker to show the dorpdown list

Comment: Here is a similar issue for windows platform on GitHub : [Request a feature to open a Picker selection window](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15001).

Answer (score 1):

You need run the `Focus()` event on the [main thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread#run-code-on-the-ui-thread). I use a Button to trigger the Picker and its data(item list) is displayed.

```
void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
    {
          if (picker.IsFocused)
              picker.Unfocus();

          picker.Focus();
    });
        
}
```

Comment: hey i tried your solution. it didn't work but as i checked the values picker.IsFocused remains false and picker.Focus(); does not change the value. any idea why?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Are you also triggering the picker via a Button? Can you help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post?